# New Saasu API for import product

Tags: php, magento

I need to import the Magento products on Saasu using new API (Oauth) but not able to found any help regarding how to pass the product details with the new API. I asked the same for Saasu support, but they don't provide any help and working example. Needed help if anyone has knowledge about it.

http://help.saasu.com/api/

Comment: Is there anyone having any working example?

Comment: Similar issue I am facing, Is there any solution to anyone.